# Order parameter for spin-1 ising model

Tags: ising-model, ferromagnetism

I'm curious what the order parameter would be for a spin-1 Ising model for magnetism and anti-ferromagnetism. So if spin's can take the value's -1,0 and 1.

Comment: I think that the reason you are not getting answers is that the question is too ambiguous: which spin-1 Ising model (that is, which Hamiltonian; note that there are many different versions of this model, depending on which phenomena you want to model)? An order parameter to discuss which phase transitions (that is, between which phases; note that, depending on your Hamiltonian, the phase diagram can display a large number of different phases)?

Comment: Now, if you want a generic answer, then if you're interested in a phase transition at which some symmetry is spontaneously broken, you must choose a local observable that (typically) has zero average in the symmetric phase and nonzero average in the broken-symmetry phase.